# Why isn't my code returning the original message?

Tags: c++, encryption, codeblocks, message

Here is a link to my assignment: [image: pict]

The user input and encrypting were easy, but I can't seem to decrypt the encryption. The job is to input one letter, it would go ahead ten letters(which would be the encryption), then go back ten letters (which would be the decryption.

I have tried messing around with the for loops but I did not really work.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char m; //Declare character
    cin >> m; // Input Character
    int ma = (int)m; // Convert character to integer
    int c; // Declare ciphertext
    for (int i=0; i<=10; i++) {
        c = ma + i;
        if (c > 122) {
            c = 97;
        }
    }

    char cc = char(c);
    cout << " " << endl;
    cout << "You ciphertext is:" << endl;
    cout << cc << endl;
    int cb = (int)cc;
    //cb = cb - 10;
    int nm;
    for (int b = 0; b>=10; b++) {
        nm = cb - b;
        if (nm < 97) {
            nm = 122;
        }
    }
    char mb = (char)nm;
    cout << "You message is" << endl;
    cout << mb << endl;
}
```

So here is what I expect: when I input "a" the ciphertext should be "k" and the decrypted message should be "a".

Comment: Use std::cout or gdb to see what's going on in your program

Comment: Where do I put it?

Comment: Why are you using a for loop ```(int i=0; i<=10; i++)``` ?

Comment: I'm just a kid. I don't know what debugging is and I spent all night all this. I can't figure it out.

Comment: what is the intererest of the `for (int i=0; i<=10; i++) {...}` ? it is like doing `i = 10; ...`

Comment: @Croppi So I can add by ten, but if it goes above 122 (which is the ascii equivalent of "z"), it will reset to "a"

Comment: and your problem comes because of `for (int b = 0; b>=10; b++) {` which stop immediately because o is not >= 10

Comment: Because I don't want the number to go above 122

Comment: @bruno is amazing!!!! THaNK YOU!!!

Comment: @JohnBob look at your code removing the first _for_ and just considering the case of _i_ valuing 10, and fully removing the second _for_

Comment: @JohnBob ok ;-) however check your algo works whatever the value, I have some doubt about that ...

Comment: Ok, but now here is a problem. When I input "z" it is not returning j or z

Comment: @JohnBob this is why I said I have doubt, your algo is not revertive like a xor is for instance. The simple way to encode and decode is to do a xor wit a given value, whatever X for a given Y X^Y^Y is X, so the same way to encode and decode, just doing ^Y in both case, after you can add a roll in one direction to encode then on the reverse direction to decode (a roll, not a shift to not loose bits). etc etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in remark

```
for (int i=0; i<=10; i++) {
    c = ma + i;
    if (c > 122) {
        c = 97;
    }
}
```

does

```
{
   int i = 10;

    c = ma + i;
    if (c > 122) {
        c = 97;
    }
}
```

because there *c* is reassigned so the previous turn as no impact on the current, and only the last counts.

Also

```
for (int b = 0; b>=10; b++) {
    nm = cb - b;
    if (nm < 97) {
        nm = 122;
    }
}
```

does nothing because the test `b>=10` is immediately false *b* valuing 0

Independently of these errors the used encoding is not revertible for a lot of values, and there is no constraint on the character to encode, it can have any code supported by a *char*.

A simple way to encode and decode is to do a xor with a given value, whatever *X* for a given *Y* `((X^Y)^Y) == X)`, so the same way to encode and decode, just doing `^Y` in both case.

An other revertible way is a roll in one direction to encode then on the reverse direction to decode. Warning a roll, not a shift to not loose bits.

An other way is to encode exchanging some bits (for instance the lower 4 bits with the 4 higher ones supposing a *char* as at least 8 bits), and to do the same to decode.

Of course you can mix these ways rather than to just do one of them.

Of course you can use a way not based on a formula, for instance  deciding for each letter an other one to replace it (a -> Z, b -> 0 etc and the reverse to decode)

There are an infinity of ways to encode/decode

Comment: I already solved the issue but since you helped me the most, I will make your answer best.

Answer (score 1):

Your "decryption" loop never executes:

```
for (int b = 0; b>=10; b++) {
```

This for loop says: start with `b` = 0, then loop as long as it's greater than 10. Well, 0 is not greater than 10, so no looping.

To undo the first loop you probably wanted this:

```
for (int b = 0; b<=10; b++) {
```

By the way, the loops simply repeat the same operation 10 times, so you can just drop the loops:

```
int OFFSET = 10;
int LOWER_LIMIT = (int)'a';
int UPPER_LIMIT = (int)'z';
int RANGE_LENGTH = UPPER_LIMIT - LOWER_LIMIT + 1;

// encrypt
c = ma + OFFSET;
if (c > UPPER_LIMIT) {
    c -= RANGE_LENGTH;
}

// decrypt
nm = cb - OFFSET;
if (nm < LOWER_LIMIT) {
    nm += RANGE_LENGTH;
}
```

Comment: I don't want it to equal 97 as final. If it exceeds 122, I want it keep counting from 97. Example: 115 + 10 = 100. When you do 115 + 10, it exceeds 122, so there is 3 counts left. It will start at 97 and end at 100 if u know what I mean.

Comment: @JohnBob there is no limit on the allowed value for the character, it is not only a..z

Comment: @JohnBob your original code's loops didn't do what you describe. I've edited my answer to do what you want, of course assuming the inputs are in the valid range.

Comment: @JohnBob I suspect you used a loop in case you'd have to "wrap around" more than once. That would only happen if you changed your `10` to a number higher than `122 - 97`, or in my edited code if OFFSET > RANGE_LENGTH. You could trivially handle that case by changing one keyword to another in my answer, I'll let you figure out which.

Comment: For extra credit you can look up `%` aka the modulus operator.

Comment: @bruno that's hardly more readable to me. If anything, maybe `LOWER_LIMIT = (int)'a';`. Hard-coding the encoding of letters is a bad idea, and it's not good to get new coders used to the idea that they can make such assumptions.

Comment: Encryption is always done on numbers only. The fact that ASCII happens to be one mapping of letters to numbers is irrelevant to the concept of encryption and should be handled separately in an I/O step.

Comment: @bruno I'm not sure what you meant to say, but I'm not the one who made the assumption that 97 is 'a'. All I'm saying is that it's very bad practice to make that assumption. Even for beginners. I know it seems "easy", but it gets you into bad habits that will bite you when you write real code that has to deal with real text. I edited my code to deal with "letters between a and z", not "numbers between 97 and 122". The newly-posted original problem OP is solving is talking about letters, so then the numbers 97 and 122 should never appear in the code. Let the compiler do the conversion.

Comment: ah ok it seems I understood the reverse of what you said, because of the 97 / 122 in your previous version of code. Is ok, midnight for me, time to sleep. Have fun

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution. When you check if the ascii of the character is bigger than 122 you have to do in addition some mathematical operations. You can't just say

```
if (c > 122) {
   c = 97;
}
```

because all the last 10 character would be converted to "a".

I think a more elegant way to encrypt/decrypt a single character is the following:

```
int main() {
    char c; //Declare character
    cin >> c; // Input Character

    int ciphertext = c + 10;
    if (ciphertext > 122)
        ciphertext = ciphertext - 123 + 97;
    cout << "You ciphertext is:" << (char)ciphertext << endl;

    int deciphertext = ciphertext - 10;
    if (deciphertext < 97)
        deciphertext = 123 - (97 - deciphertext);
    cout << "You original is:" << (char)deciphertext << endl;

}
```

Note that if the ascii value of the char exceedes the upper limit it starts to count from the letter "a".

Comment: that does not work for a lot of characters, in fact for all character except betweeb a and z

Comment: @bruno I thought we were working with only characters between a and z. Isn't that true?

Comment: Read again the question, it is just speaking about "a character" without any constraint about it, you was influenced by the OP proposal ;-)

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right. With this in mind, what's the meaning of "Ok, but now here is a problem. When I input "z" it is not returning j or z."?

Comment: Why are you saying that ? In ASCII code z is 122, 122 + 10 = 132, it is greater that 122 so encoding is 132 - 123  + 97 = 106. Decoding is 106 - 10 so 96, it is less than 97 so 123 - (97 - 96) = 122, being z